# Yii ajaxSubmitButton update option and validate

Tags: ajax, validation, yii

I have an active form with *validateOnSubmit* option. Form has ajaxSubmitButton:

```
CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Next', '', array('update' => '#answer-form')
```

The problem is, that form updated without result of validation. What is the best way to do it right? Something like this:

```
CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Дальше', '', array('valid' => '#answer-form')
```

Comment: Do you have `enableAjaxValidation=>true` and `$form->error($model, 'attribute')` ?

Comment: Of course. Form validated (I can see error messages some times), but after that it's update content.

Comment: You probably don't need an `ajaxSubmitButton`, it won't work as you expect for this case. I'd try `clientOptions.afterValidate` and javascript for multi step form...

Comment: Here is a working example, you can check out the model, view & controller: http://www.essential-strategy.com/activeformwithajax?view=clientvalidation